# How do you efficiently calculate YTD values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I implemented the following code to calculate the YTD sum in Pandas:

```
def calculateYTDSum(df:pd.DataFrame)->pd.DataFrame:
    '''Calculates the YTD sum of numeric values in a dataframe.
    
    This assumes the input dataframe contains a "quarter" column of type "Quarter"
    '''
    
    ans = (df
           .sort_values(by='quarter', ascending=True)
           .assign(_year = lambda x: x['quarter'].apply(lambda x: x.year))
           .groupby('_year')
           .apply(lambda x: x
                  .set_index('quarter')
                  .cumsum()
                )
           .drop(columns=['_year'])
           .reset_index()
           .drop(columns=['_year'])
           .sort_values(by='quarter', ascending=False)
        )
    
    return ans
```

To see it in action consider the following:

```
@dataclass
class Quarter:  # This class is used elsewhere in the codebase
    year:int
    quarter:int
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.year} Q{self.quarter}'
    
    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return self.year*4 + self.quarter
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return hash(self) < hash(other)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'quarter': [Quarter(2020, 4), 
                Quarter(2020, 3),
                Quarter(2020, 2),
                Quarter(2020, 1),
                Quarter(2019, 4),
                Quarter(2019, 3),
                Quarter(2019, 2),
                Quarter(2019, 1)],
    'quantity1' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    'quantity2' : [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
})
```

Then you have:

`df =`

|  | quarter | quantity1 | quantity2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020 Q4 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2020 Q3 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020 Q2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2020 Q1 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2019 Q4 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 2019 Q3 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 2019 Q2 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 2019 Q1 | 1 | 3 |

and `df.pipe(calculateYTDSum) =`

|  | quarter | quantity1 | quantity2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2020 Q4 | 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 2020 Q3 | 3 | 6 |
| 6 | 2020 Q2 | 2 | 4 |
| 7 | 2020 Q1 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 2019 Q4 | 4 | 12 |
| 1 | 2019 Q3 | 3 | 9 |
| 2 | 2019 Q2 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 2019 Q1 | 1 | 3 |

However, even for a small sample like the above, the calculation takes ~4ms - and tbh it looks unmaintainable.

I welcome any recommendations on Python tooling, libraries, Pandas extensions, or code changes that would improve the performance and/or simplicity of the code.

Comment: Do you need the second drop after the reset_index?

Comment: Oddly I do, else the `_year` column from the `groupby` is retained (in fact I do the first `drop` to remove `_year` so that I can `reset index`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The current [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) code computes an extra `cumsum` (`_year`) and requires a lot of extra index manipulation (set + drop + reset + drop).

Instead use [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html), which is more idiomatic and ~20x faster for larger dataframes.

---

#### Issues

This [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) adds a lot of overhead:

```
...groupby('_year').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('quarter').cumsum())
```

- Sets an index
- **Computes an extra `cumsum` over `_year`**
- Later requires dropping the `_year` index and `_year` column

We can see this intermediate state by stopping the chain early:

```
(df.sort_values(by='quarter', ascending=True)
   .assign(_year=lambda x: x['quarter'].apply(lambda q: q.year))
   .groupby('_year').apply(lambda g: g.set_index('quarter').cumsum())
)

#                quantity1  quantity2  _year
# _year quarter                             
# 2019  2019 Q1          1          3   2019
#       2019 Q2          2          6   4038
#       2019 Q3          3          9   6057
#       2019 Q4          4         12   8076
# 2020  2020 Q1          1          2   2020
#       2020 Q2          2          4   4040
#       2020 Q3          3          6   6060
#       2020 Q4          4          8   8080
```

---

#### Suggestions

[`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) is fast and idiomatic, but we lose the `quarter` column:

```
(df.sort_values(by='quarter', ascending=True)
   .assign(_year=lambda x: x['quarter'].apply(lambda q: q.year))
   .groupby('_year').cumsum()
)

#    quantity1  quantity2
# 7          1          3
# 6          2          6
# 5          3          9
# 4          4         12
# 3          1          2
# 2          2          4
# 1          3          6
# 0          4          8
```

So we can just [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.DataFrame.join.html) this [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) result back to `df[['quarter']]`:

```
df[['quarter']].join(
    df.sort_values(by='quarter', ascending=True)
      .assign(_year=lambda x: x['quarter'].apply(lambda q: q.year))
      .groupby('_year').cumsum()
)

#    quarter  quantity1  quantity2
# 0  2020 Q4          4          8
# 1  2020 Q3          3          6
# 2  2020 Q2          2          4
# 3  2020 Q1          1          2
# 4  2019 Q4          4         12
# 5  2019 Q3          3          9
# 6  2019 Q2          2          6
# 7  2019 Q1          1          3
```

---

#### Timings

At 10K rows, the [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) approach is ~21x faster than [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
%%timeit
df[['quarter']].join(
    df.sort_values(by='quarter', ascending=True)
      .assign(_year=lambda x: x['quarter'].apply(lambda q: q.year))
      .groupby('_year').cumsum()
)

# 74 ms ± 1.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
(df.sort_values(by='quarter', ascending=True)
   .assign(_year=lambda x: x['quarter'].apply(lambda q: q.year))
   .groupby('_year').apply(lambda g: g.set_index('quarter').cumsum())
   .drop(columns=['_year'])
   .reset_index()
   .drop(columns=['_year'])
   .sort_values(by='quarter', ascending=False)
)

# 1.58 s ± 16.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Testing data for reference:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(123)
n = 2500
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'quarter': [Quarter(y, q) for y in range(1000, 1000 + n) for q in (4, 3, 2, 1)],
    'quantity1': rng.integers(5, size=n * 4),
    'quantity2': rng.integers(10, size=n * 4),
})

#       quarter  quantity1  quantity2
# 0     1000 Q4          0          8
# 1     1000 Q3          3          5
# ...       ...        ...        ...
# 9998  3499 Q2          1          7
# 9999  3499 Q1          0          4
# 
# [10000 rows x 3 columns]
```